# OPENLDAP - ldapwhoami not working binding securely, but other applications does

Tags: ssl, tls, ldap, openldap

I tried adding `TLS hard` in slapd.conf but it says

> unknown directive  inside backend database definition.

Tying by CLI the command

```
ldapwhoami.exe -H ldap://myldap.company.com -v -D "uid=dds,ou=accounting,dc=company,dc=com" -x -w mysecret
```

works

> Result: Success (0)

But the same command with `-H ldaps://myldap.company.com` gives

> ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

This error with command option `-Z`

> ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11) additional info: error:1416F086:SSL  routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
> ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

With the software Ldapadmin connects fine either with "SSL" (on port 636) and "TLS" option (on port 389).

Also on linux it's working (after I added the certificate and told ldap.conf to use it)

EDIT: title changed

Comment: But your error messages show that you don't have TLS available yet... I think you need to ask about how to properly enable TLS on your server _before_ you can disable non-TLS usage.

Comment: same configuration: on windows ldapadmin works (ca certificate installed with certmgr.msc), on windows a java application can connect and wireshark shows TLS data. It's openldap tools that does not work